# C# serialized count information doesn't match the number of items

Tags: c#, serialization

first of all thanks for your time spent on reading this question. My problem is as following i have 4 classes

```
[Serializable]
class Base
{
    protected int x;
    protected int y;
    protected int z;
}

[Serializable]
class Sub : Base
{
    private bool b;
}

[Serializable]
class CompareByX : Comparer<Sub>
{
...
}

[Serializable]
class CustomObject
{
    Base s1 = new HashSet<Base>();
    SortedSet<Sub> s2 = new SortedSet<Sub>(new CompareByX());
    int x;
}

class CustomObjectManager
{
    HashSet<CustomObject> cos1 = new HashSet<CustomObject>();
}
```

Well I guess i figured out that much but serializing and deserializing this way throws me **The serialized Count information doesn't match the number of items** Exception which kinda confuses me. Okay got it fixed myself. Thanks for the help anyway. Note [NotSerialized] is inherited.

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(FileStream, cos1);

BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
CustomObject[] bData = (HashSet<CustomObject>)bFormatter.Deserialize(fs);
```

Comment: `[NonSerializable]` is not an existing attribute. And this has been asked before.

Comment: what doesn't exsist? [NonSerialized](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs). and see [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=_Y0rWd-Q2xkC&pg=PA517&lpg=PA517&dq=ben+albahari+serialize+inheritance&source=bl&ots=R9BwV7WE1m&sig=EuQyVEpoMt8jqJbgoVu2JxucqMY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rKVGVOezMcT4mAW8ioGIDQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=ben%20albahari%20serialize%20inheritance&f=false). for some info on serializing. also I highly recommend those books.

Comment: Throws an exception I wrote in bold sorry i forgot to write it was an Exception that was thrown at me ^.^